# Is there spam or vandalism in this suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

While working the Suggested Edit Review Queue, I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25491223). At the time I saw it, it had one Reject vote for Spam/Vandalism.

It's mainly adding in the code from pastebin, which uses [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). I don't know if the move to 4.0 on Stack Overflow makes this edit unacceptable, but the vote used seems overly harsh.

Is there something else wrong here I'm not seeing? There's other issues with the edit I could understand rejecting it for, but nothing that looks like spam or vandalism which carries a much harsher penalty than normal rejects.

Comment: I guess the edit was rejected because your edit comment didn't make clear that you were adding the OP's own code from their own link. In the review queue what it looks like is that you added code to someone's question that wasn't there before, and your comment which just says *"added the code"* gives no information about why this code should be included in the question. That comment is completely superfluous because reviewers can *see* that you've added code in your proposed edit.

Comment: @kaya3 It’s not my edit, I came across it while looking at reviews. I guess the edit summary is likely the issue though the reviewer should have noticed the codepen link in the question.

Comment: Oh, my mistake; I didn't notice that the edit was proposed by a different user.

Comment: @kaya3 It's actually not clear in the question itself, I'll edit to clarify.